# Using Select query to display data in a data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview, webforms

I am trying to display a table data of my db in a DataGridView.here is my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{              
  SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHIRWANIPC;" + 
"Initial Catalog=TEST DATABASE;" + "Integrated Security=True");

  myConnection.Open();

  SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer", myConnection);

  SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(objcmd);

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  //adp.Fill(dt);

  DataGridView.DataSource = adp.Fill(dt);



}
```

The code is not giving any error now but but it dosent display the data from my table in my grid ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `class` name instead of object (instance) name of [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), check in the html what is ID/name of `DataGridView`, It is probably Win Forms and you do not have DataBind method there. DataBind method is defined for `GridView` for ASP.net. Find more about DataGridView [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
 DataGridViewObject.DataSource = adp.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer to my quetion , hope it helps others who are new to this

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHIRWANIPC;" + "Initial  Catalog=TEST DATABASE;" + "Integrated Security=True");
myConnection.Open();
SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer", myConnection);
//objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(objcmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
//MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString());
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of DatagridView:

```
 DataGridView dview = new DataGridView();
 ....
 dview.DataSource = adp.Fill(dt);
 dview.DataBind();
```

Comment: i have done this

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            adp.Fill(dt);

            DataGridView DView = new DataGridView();

            DView.DataSource = dt;

            DView.DataBind();

it does not recognize DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

You are directly accessing DataGridView properties and tryingto add data to the class. You need to create and an instance of a DataGridView first. Then assign the datable to the object.
Than bind the data to the DataGridView, otherwise the data is not bound to the control and will not be displayed.

```
DataGridView view = new DataGridView();
dview.DataSource = adp.Fill(dt);
dview.DataBind();
```

Comment: i have corrected my code ,and data bind is not needed as i learned it after googling ,the code is not giving any errors but its not also displaying table data in the grid view ,what am i missing here ,m i not executing the query , this is what i think i am doing wrong

Comment: Sorry you are not executing the query. You will need to add objcmd.ExecuteReader()

Comment: now it throws this error There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Comment: Can you please update the code so we can see what is happening.

Comment: SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data 

Source=SHIRWANIPC;" + "Initial Catalog=TEST DATABASE;" + "Integrated 

Security=True");

            myConnection.Open();

            SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 

Customer", myConnection);

            objcmd.ExecuteReader();

            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(objcmd);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            adp.Fill(dt);

            DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: this is what i have done ,its executin properly but not displaying the table in the datagrid view

Comment: and when i run my project it throws an exception saying There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Comment: SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHIRWANIPC;" + "Initial Catalog=TEST DATABASE;" + "Integrated Security=True"); myConnection.Open();SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer", myConnection);objcmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dtTable.Load(sqlDataReader);
                sqlDataReader.Close();
            }
            DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: this is not working ,giving error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()' "

Comment: looking at the code if you delete objcmd.ExecuteReader() as this is been used in the using function.

Comment: I have tested the code and it seems to working fine for me could the problem be somewhere else ?

Comment: i have posted the solution as an answer below ,have a look at it if you wish to ,thanks any ways for being there (Y) ,you have been helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You are not exectuting the query

```
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer", myConnection);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); using
    (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        dt.Load(sqlDataReader);
        sqlDataReader.Close();
    }
    DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```